# how to use QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

Can somebody please provide an explanation, or better yet a short example, of how to use the `RubberBandDrag` enum value in `QGraphicsView`?  PyQt5 would be great, but I can translate from the C++ version if that is preferred for whomever can provide a helpful exmaple.

`NoDrag` and `ScrollHandDrag` are relatively easy to understand (`NoDrag` makes the mouse a pointer and you can capture clicks at certain locations, `ScrollHandDrag` makes the mouse a hand and you can implement click and drag to scroll around), but I'm unclear on what `RubberBandDrag` can be used for.

Before somebody says "go read the docs", here is the information provided

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html

> enum QGraphicsView::DragMode
>
> QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag
>
> A rubber band will appear. Dragging the mouse will set the rubber band
>   geometry, and all items covered by the rubber band are selected. This
>   mode is disabled for non-interactive views.

This is clear but I'm not sure how I could actually use `RubberBandDrag`.  Is there a way to use this to drag points of a `QPolygon` around after initial placement?  That would be really useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#DragMode-enum) flag only serves to activate the internal [`QRubberBand`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html):

[image]

And the QRubberBand in general only aims to visualize a selected area and in the case of QGraphicsView select the items below that area if they are selectable(enable QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable flag).

---

According to your last question: *Is there a way to use this to drag points of a QPolygon around after initial placement? That would be really useful*,  it seems to me that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since it seems that the use of *drag* in the terminology makes you think that it serves to drag elements, because no, that drag refers to the way of creating the rubber band.

<s>In a few moments I will show how to implement the drag of the vertices to modify the *QPolygon*.</s>

The following shows how to modify the position of the vertices by dragging the mouse:

```py
import math

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GripItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    circle = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    circle.addEllipse(QtCore.QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))
    square = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    square.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(-15, -15, 30, 30))

    def __init__(self, annotation_item, index):
        super(GripItem, self).__init__()
        self.m_annotation_item = annotation_item
        self.m_index = index

        self.setPath(GripItem.circle)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("green"))
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 2))
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setZValue(11)
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setPath(GripItem.square)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))
        super(GripItem, self).hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setPath(GripItem.circle)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("green"))
        super(GripItem, self).hoverLeaveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.setSelected(False)
        super(GripItem, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.isEnabled():
            self.m_annotation_item.movePoint(self.m_index, value)
        return super(GripItem, self).itemChange(change, value)


class PolygonAnnotation(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PolygonAnnotation, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_points = []
        self.setZValue(10)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 2))
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.m_items = []

    def addPoint(self, p):
        self.m_points.append(p)
        self.setPolygon(QtGui.QPolygonF(self.m_points))
        item = GripItem(self, len(self.m_points) - 1)
        self.scene().addItem(item)
        self.m_items.append(item)
        item.setPos(p)

    def movePoint(self, i, p):
        if 0 <= i < len(self.m_points):
            self.m_points[i] = self.mapFromScene(p)
            self.setPolygon(QtGui.QPolygonF(self.m_points))

    def move_item(self, index, pos):
        if 0 <= index < len(self.m_items):
            item = self.m_items[index]
            item.setEnabled(False)
            item.setPos(pos)
            item.setEnabled(True)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for i, point in enumerate(self.m_points):
                self.move_item(i, self.mapToScene(point))
        return super(PolygonAnnotation, self).itemChange(change, value)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
        super(PolygonAnnotation, self).hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))
        super(PolygonAnnotation, self).hoverLeaveEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    w = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)

    polygon_item = PolygonAnnotation()
    scene.addItem(polygon_item)
    r = 100
    sides = 10

    for i in range(sides):
        angle = 2 * math.pi * i / sides
        x = r * math.cos(angle)
        y = r * math.sin(angle)
        p = QtCore.QPointF(x, y) + QtCore.QPointF(200, 200)
        polygon_item.addPoint(p)

    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```