# Make GraphicsItems editable by mouse action and mouse events in a Graphicscene

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I am currently writing a interactive GUI, the code below inserts nodes and respective edges in a continues manner by mouse events beginning and ending the draw session by making a  double click event (based on this post  [Join QGraphicsItem and QPainter in same GraphicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809809/join-qgraphicsitem-and-qpainter-in-same-graphicsscene)). I want to make the node and edges editable in the sense that after being drawn the user can move around the node position by mouse event as in the following example.
[how to use QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156142/how-to-use-qgraphicsviewrubberbanddrag),

The code

```
class WindowClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowClass, self).__init__(parent)
        view = QGraphicsView()
        view.setMouseTracking(True)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        scene = SceneClass(self)
        view.setScene(scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.resize(640, 480)

class SceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SceneClass, self).__init__(QRectF(-1000, -1000, 2000, 2000), parent)
        self._edge_item = None
        self.pos = None
        self.pos_end = None
        self.node_start = None
        self.node_end = None

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            "Agregar Nodo"
            self.node_start = Node()
            self.node_start.setPos(event.scenePos())
            self.addItem(self.node_start)
            "Agregar Edge"
            self._edge_item = Edge()
            self._edge_item.src = self.node_start
            self.addItem(self._edge_item)
            if self.node_end:
                self.node_end = None
                self.node_start = None

            self.node_end = self.node_start

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.node_end:
            "Agregar Nodo"
            self.node_start = Node()
            self.node_start.setPos(event.scenePos())
            self.addItem(self.node_start)
            self.node_end = self.node_start
            "Agregar Edge"
            self._edge_item = Edge()
            self._edge_item.src = self.node_start
            self.addItem(self._edge_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._edge_item and self.node_end:
            self._edge_item.p1 = event.scenePos()
        super(SceneClass, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Node(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, rect=QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20), parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__(rect, parent)
        self.edges = []
        self.setZValue(1)
        self.setBrush(Qt.darkGray)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        self.edges.append(edge)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange:
            self.setBrush(Qt.green if value else Qt.darkGray)
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for edge in self.edges:
                edge.adjust()
        return super(Node, self).itemChange(change, value)

class Edge(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Edge, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3))
        self._src = None
        self._dst = None

    @property
    def src(self):
        return self._src

    @src.setter
    def src(self, node):
        self._src = node
        self._src.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    @property
    def dst(self):
        return self._dst

    @dst.setter
    def dst(self, node):
        self._dst = node
        self._dst.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self.line().p1()

    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        line.setP1(p)
        self.setLine(line)

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return self.line().p2()

    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        line.setP2(p)
        self.setLine(line)

    def adjust(self):
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        if self.src:
            self.p1 = self.src.pos()
            self.p2 = self.src.pos()
        if self.dst:
            self.p2 = self.dst.pos()
```

I have tried to initiate by adding a hoover event in the edge class, but after setting to accept hover event and creating a function to instruct action on this event, this function does not trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of the OP is incorrect so I had to modify it a little so that it follows the sequence correctly.

On the other hand the behavior of moving the items is already implemented by default but it is necessary that the mouse events are sent to the items, and for this it is necessary to call the super() method of the mouseXEvent methods.

```py
class SceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SceneClass, self).__init__(QRectF(-1000, -1000, 2000, 2000), parent)
        self._edge_item = None
        self._last_node = None

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self._last_node:
                self._last_node = None
                self._edge_item = None
            else:
                node = Node()
                node.setPos(event.scenePos())
                self.addItem(node)
                self._edge_item = Edge()
                self._edge_item.src = node
                self.addItem(self._edge_item)
                self._last_node = node
            return
        super(SceneClass, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._last_node:

            node = Node()
            node.setPos(event.scenePos())
            self.addItem(node)
            self._edge_item.dst = node

            self._edge_item = Edge()
            self._edge_item.src = node
            self.addItem(self._edge_item)

            self._last_node = node
            return
        super(SceneClass, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._edge_item:
            self._edge_item.p1 = event.scenePos()
        super(SceneClass, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)


class Node(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, rect=QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20), parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__(rect, parent)
        self.edges = []
        self.setZValue(1)
        self.setBrush(Qt.darkGray)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        self.edges.append(edge)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange:
            self.setBrush(Qt.green if value else Qt.darkGray)
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for edge in self.edges:
                edge.adjust()
        return super(Node, self).itemChange(change, value)


class Edge(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Edge, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3))
        self._src = None
        self._dst = None

    @property
    def src(self):
        return self._src

    @src.setter
    def src(self, node):
        self._src = node
        self._src.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    @property
    def dst(self):
        return self._dst

    @dst.setter
    def dst(self, node):
        self._dst = node
        self._dst.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self.line().p1()

    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        line.setP1(p)
        self.setLine(line)

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return self.line().p2()

    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        line.setP2(p)
        self.setLine(line)

    def adjust(self):
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        if self.src:
            self.p1 = self.src.pos()
            self.p2 = self.src.pos()
        if self.dst:
            self.p2 = self.dst.pos()
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response, I am new to pyqt so I will revise my code to see the reason for your corrections, this was really helpful.